# CORS error - Working in Chrome but fails in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have below script which doing a ajax call and trying to redirect to some url. Problem here is below code working fine in Chrome but fails in IE.

```
function LoginSubmit() {
        debugger;

        $('#loginform').validate();

        if ($('#loginform').valid()) {
            myApp.showProgress();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Authentication/Login",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("form[name=loginform]").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('ConvertInsuredLogin').html("");
                    if (data != null && data.OldAccountNumber) {
                        InsuredLogin(data.OldAccountNumber);
                    }
                    else if (data != null && data.ReturnUrl) {
                        //error line
                        window.location.replace(data.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else {
                        var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                        newDoc.write(data);
                        newDoc.close();
                    }
                },
                complete: function () { myApp.hideProgress(); }
            });

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is a Javascript/jQuery/Ajax error, not related to C# nor ASP.NET. Please do not add tags that are not related to the question

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, noted. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, what means 'fails'? Possibly IE doesn't know `debugger;`

Comment: @Holger, fails means here it not redirecting to data.ReturnUrl wherein same code is working in Chrome and redirect.